# Why SetOptions[$FrontEnd, PrintPrecision -> 16] affects one plot ticks but not the other?

Tags: graphics, bugs, front-end, precision-and-accuracy, ticks

**Bug introduced in 11.0 and persisting through 11.1.0**

---

in V 11.1 I noticed something strange.

Compare this

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd,PrintPrecision->15]
f[x_]:=Piecewise[{{0,x<1},{1,True}}];
Plot[f[x],{x,0,10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd,PrintPrecision->16]
f[x_]:=Piecewise[{{0,x<1},{1,True}}];
Plot[f[x],{x,0,10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But this affects only the above plot. Other plot I tried such as below is OK

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd,PrintPrecision->16]
f[x_]:=Sin[x];
Plot[f[x],{x,0,10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Any idea why this happens? Btw, the above only happens in version 11 and 11.1. On version 10.4, it does not happen. Here is screen shot on version 10.4

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It only happens on version 11 and 11.1  and when I change from 15 to 16 `PrintPrecision`.

Comment: It is `PlotRange` what triggers this behavior: try `Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> {{0, 10.}, {0., 1.}}]` or simply `Graphics[{}, Axes -> True, PlotRange -> {{0, 1.}, {0., 1.}}]`.

Comment: It is better don't change the options permanently, use `$FrontEndSession` instead of `$FrontEnd`: `SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, PrintPrecision -> 16]`.

Comment: Reproduced with versions 11.0.1 and 11.1.0 on Windows 7 x64, versions 10.4.1 and 8.0.4 do not have this behavior.

Comment: Have you reported this to the tech support?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov No I have not. I was not sure if it is a bug or not. Thanks.

Comment: Bug reproduced in MMA 11.1.1 (Windows 64-bit)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug of `Graphics` in version 11, here is a minimal code sample reproducing the problem:

```
SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, PrintPrecision -> 16]
Graphics[{}, Axes -> True, PlotRange -> {{0, 1.}, {0., 1.}}]
```

[image: screenshot]

The second `Graphics` on the screenshot above is the same graphics after automatic scaling when I typed `//` after it and then deleted. Obviously it is an additional related bug.

A workaround is to add `BaseStyle -> {PrintPrecision -> 6}`:

```
Graphics[{}, Axes -> True, PlotRange -> {{0, 1.}, {0., 1.}}, 
 BaseStyle -> {PrintPrecision -> 6}]
```

or wrap the whole `Graphics` with `Style`:

```
Style[Graphics[{}, Axes -> True, PlotRange -> {{0, 1.}, {0., 1.}}], PrintPrecision -> 6]
```

Another way is to set the option `NumberMarks -> True` *instead* of `PrintPrecision -> 16` if you wish to see all the digits:

```
SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, PrintPrecision -> 6, NumberMarks -> True]
```