# Axes of ListPlot

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I would like to draw a list plot with the Y-axis from from 0.00 to 0.40 (rounded to two decimal points). However, it turned out to be that the numbers on the Y-axis have too many numbers after the decimal point. Could you please help me with the issue?

[image]

```
ListPlot[
  {{-12, .072368}, {-6, .059211}, {-2, 0.1710532}, {2, .2565797}, 
   {7, .27631613}, {13, .164474}}, 
  Filling -> Axis, PlotRange -> All, PlotTheme -> "Detailed", 
  ImageSize -> 500, PlotLabel -> "The prob.", 
  FrameLabel -> {"x", "p(x)"}, 
  LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Roboto", FontSize -> 11}]
```

Comment: Without the code that generated the plot, it will be very difficult to tell what went wrong and how to fix it

Comment: Try to use the option: `FrameTicks -> {{{0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4}, None}, {Automatic, None}}`. As a variant giving a bit more control try this: `FrameTicks -> {{{{0, "0.0"}, {0.1, "0.1"}, {0.2, "0.2"}, {0.3, "0.3"}, {0.4, "0.4"}}, None}, {Automatic, None}}` .

Comment: Thank you! I would update the results and codes here.

Comment: Original Codes: ListPlot[{{-12, .072368}, {-6, .059211},
          {-2, 0.1710532},
          {2, .2565797},
          {7, .27631613},
          {13, .164474}}, Filling -> Axis, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotTheme -> "Detailed", 
 ImageSize -> 500, PlotLabel -> "The prob.", 
 FrameLabel -> {"x", "p(x)" }, 
 LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Roboto", FontSize -> 11}]

Comment: The graph looks well according to Alexei's suggestion (after we apply "FrameTicks").

Comment: I do not reproduce the issue: https://imgur.com/a/TZPq6Rn

Comment: Try `SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, PrintPrecision -> 6]` and rerun your code.

Comment: Possibly related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/143937/4999,
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3752/4999

Answer (score 2):

ListPlot from 0 to 0.40 with FrameTicks to the second decimal

```
ListPlot[{{-12, .072368}, {-6, .059211}, {-2, 
   0.1710532}, {2, .2565797}, {7, .27631613}, {13, .164474}}, 
 Filling -> Axis, PlotRange -> {All, {0, 0.4}}, 
 PlotTheme -> "Detailed", ImageSize -> 500, PlotLabel -> "The prob.", 
 Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"x", "p(x)"}, 
 LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Roboto", FontSize -> 11}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{{0, N[1/10, 2], N[2/10, 2], N[3/10, 2], N[4/10, 2]}, 
    None}, {Automatic, None}}]
```

[image: ListPlot from 0 to 0.40 with FrameTicks to the second decimal]

Comment: Thanks for everyone for your kind help!!

Answer (score 2):

OP's code, unaltered (V12.1.1, Mac), same as [@corey979](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/230236/axes-of-listplot#comment584020_230236):

```
ListPlot[{{-12, .072368}, {-6, .059211}, {-2, 
   0.1710532}, {2, .2565797}, {7, .27631613}, {13, .164474}}, 
 Filling -> Axis, PlotRange -> All, PlotTheme -> "Detailed", 
 ImageSize -> 500, PlotLabel -> "The prob.", 
 FrameLabel -> {"x", "p(x)"}, 
 LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Roboto", FontSize -> 11}]
```

[image]

The solutions in the other comments and answer(s) seem unnecessary.

---

Perhaps the problem is with `PrintPrecision`: Set

```
SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, PrintPrecision -> 19]
```

Then the above produces this:

[image]

If that's the problem the option can be reset (the normal value is `6`), or one can apply `Style` to the above `ListPlot`:

```
Style[ListPlot[...], PrintPrecision -> 6]
```